# Outlook Journal: Hot key to get into main text area?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Microsoft Outlook's Journal, when creating a new Item and filling in the fields, is there a hotkey for switching the insertion point to the main text area for making notes?  (Note that this is not the same as Outlook's Notes, which is a peer app to Outlook's Journal and Mail).

There is very little online about Journal.  I can't even find the name of the field for capturing text notes.  So instead, I tried to find the counterpart hotkey for email composition, i.e., to move the insertion point into the message body area.  I was hoping that it might be the same for a Journal Item.  But I haven't found that hotkey for email composition either.

I use many versions of Outlook, from 2007 to 2019.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I'm afraid there may not be a direct hotkey for this. You need to press Tab key many times to move the insertion point to the main text area. It is suggested to directly click the main text area to move the insertion point.

Comment: Thanks, Aidan.  Let's just wait for a bit before closing this out.  Maybe someone more knowledgeable than either of us will surprise us.